# How can I add an LM567 in LTspice?

Tags: integrated-circuit, ltspice, model

From searching the web it seems it is not included with the installation of LTspice, so I will have to add it as a 3rd-party model.

I am fairly new to LTspice and I'm not sure how to do this as I haven't had to yet. I haven't found information on this IC in LTspice. Does anyone know where I can get an LM567 model for LTspice?

Comment: Whoever marked this question as a duplicate pointing to an answer on how to add a model. I was asking where I can find a specific model I was having a hard time finding. The adding models link you provided did not help me solve my problem of finding the LM567 model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### LTspice's groups.io community

You should sign up for groups.io's LTspice group. It's an impressive community that is (or has been) extremely well-managed by Helmut. It's the ***second*** place to go, if the manufacturers themselves don't provide models.

It's also a place to go when asking questions about the use of LTspice, solving difficult problems you face, and in general when you need serious and thoughtful help specific to LTspice. There are many experts there. And they respond well and quickly.

What you want is [here](https://groups.io/g/LTspice/files/z_yahoo/Lib/NE567). Once you sign up (and there used to be an approval process which is easily passed), you have access to their message board and files. Please do sign up.

### LTspice common models, subcircuits, and assemblies

*(Short history note: There was first LTspice IV. Then came LTspice XVII. Then came LTspice. All of these have been built using tools that helped to allow its availability under operating systems other than Windows. However, the first two didn't obey new rules from Microsoft about file folder placement. This last one does.*)

LTspice (and LTspice XVII) have default locations where they look for assemblies, models, and subcircuits. After installing LTspice, you should familiarize yourself with their locations. It can be important to know.

In general, they will be located starting at some root folder location created during installation. In that root folder, you will find a folder called **lib**. This is where you will find three more folders: **cmp**, **sub**, and **sym**.

In the first, **cmp**, is found the default files used to hold *simple* models of parts, such as BJTs, MOSFETs, diodes, etc. You can enhance those files as you see fit and your new models will be searchable when looking to change a diode part number, for example.

In the second, **sub**, is found the provided subcircuit models that were installed. You can add to this folder, if you want. If so, LTspice will be able to find that subcircuit or model file when it looks.

In the third, **sym**, is found the assembly drawings (and their meta data) that were also installed. You can add to this folder, if you want. If so, LTspice will add those drawing symbols to the list you get when hitting the F2 key.

You can create other folders as you see fit and place them where you want. Often, this is a good idea to avoid some clutter as you accumulate models from different sources. But if you do this, you need to let LTspice know about them. It doesn't have a crystal ball. So you will need to click on the *hammer* symbol (or use the *Tools/Control Panel* menu option) to pull up the tools dialog. There, you will look for and select the tab called **Sym. & Lib. Search Parts**. And there you can add directories that LTspice should consider when looking for things you have placed elsewhere. Add them and click OK. Then restart LTspice just to be sure it knows about them.

### 567 stuff you want

You now have enough information to know where and how to save the following files.

I can provide what they have at the LTspice groups.io site. All of these files were contributed by **Michael Wilson**. You are in his debt.

*(It appears to be `idealized` [so may deviate from actual behavior] and something performed or otherwise captured during EE449 in the winter of 2011. Hopefully it still meets your needs.)*

This first file is the LTspice model for the NE567A. It can be given any file extension you want. So if you have a preference, go with it. But it is common to use **SUB** (for *subcircuit*) or **MOD** (for *model*). In this case, it's a subcircuit. So I'd recommend you use **SUB** as the file extension. Michael chose to call it **XNE567A.SUB**.

```
* C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Cal Poly\EE449Winter11\PLL ToneDetect\Phase *Detectors10a_nuVco.asc
.SUBCKT XNE567A 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
Q1 2 N016 N020 0 NPN
Q2 2 N017 N021 0 NPN
Q3 4 N017 N020 0 NPN
Q4 4 N016 N021 0 NPN
Q5 N020 3 N026 0 NPN
Q6 N021 P001 N027 0 NPN
Q7 N029 B N030 0 NPN
Q11 4 Y N022 0 NPN
Q12 4 X N023 0 NPN
Q13 1 X N022 0 NPN
Q14 1 Y N023 0 NPN
Q16 N022 N027 N031 0 NPN
Q17 N023 N026 N031 0 NPN
R1 N016 A 20k
R3 N018 N017 10k
R4 N018 N016 10k
R6 M P001 21k
R7 M 3 21k
R8 N026 N029 .5k
R9 N027 N029 .5k
R10 N030 0 2.45k
R11 4 2 10k
Q19 N031 B N034 0 NPN
R15 N034 0 2.7k
R16 4 1 10k
V3 B 0 1.35
Q20 N014 N012 N010 0 PNP
Q21 N012 N012 N011 0 PNP
Q22 N012 P002 N024 0 NPN
Q23 N012 N024 N028 0 NPN
Q24 N010 N025 N028 0 NPN
Q25 N010 1 N025 0 NPN
R18 4 N011 5k
R19 4 N010 5k
R20 N024 N028 5k
R21 N025 N028 5k
Q26 N028 N032 N033 0 NPN
R22 N033 0 5k
V8 N032 0 1.4
R23 P002 N019 1k
V9 N019 0 3.7
Q27 N013 N014 N015 0 NPN
Q28 8 N015 0 0 NPN
R24 4 N013 10k
R26 N015 0 10k
XU1 N008 6 4 0 N006 LT1018
V6 N007 0 2.5
R13 N008 N007 10k
R14 N006 N008 68k
Q15 4 N006 N002 0 2N3904
Q18 0 N006 N002 0 2N3906
Q29 Y N003 N005 0 NPN
Q30 N005 N009 P003 0 NPN
Q31 X N004 N005 0 NPN
R29 P003 0 900
R30 N001 Y 2k
R31 N001 X 2k
V7 N004 0 2
V10 N009 0 1.22
R32 4 N001 4k
V11 N003 6 -.5
R33 N006 A 6k
R34 A 4 4.0k
R35 A 0 12k
B1 0 6 I=(i(R25))*(V(2)-3.8)*2
R12 0 7 10
R25 N002 5 1
R27 4 8 10Meg
R28 4 7 100Meg
R36 5 6 2.27meg
C4 6 0 .001f
V1 N018 0 3.8
V2 M 0 2.5
.model NPN NPN
.model PNP PNP
*.lib C:\PROGRA~2\LTC\LTSPIC~1\lib\cmp\standard.bjt
.lib standard.bjt
* C3 Filter Cap\nPin 1
* C2 Loop Filter\nPin 2
* External\nPull up
* Pin 8
* Quad\nPhase
* In Phase
* Ext Cap
* Pin 3
* Pin 4
* Pin 7\nGround
* Ext Cap
* Ext Cap
.lib LTC1.lib
.backanno
.ends
```

This second file is the LTspice drawing assembly and meta data file for the NE567A. It should be provided the **ASY** extension. Michael chose to call it **XNE567A.ASY**.

```
Version 4
SymbolType CELL
LINE Normal -20 -128 -20 -112
LINE Normal 20 -128 20 -112
LINE Normal -8 -100 8 -100
RECTANGLE Normal -112 -128 112 128
ARC Normal -20 -124 4 -100 -20 -112 -8 -100
ARC Normal -4 -124 20 -100 8 -100 20 -112
WINDOW 0 0 -64 Center 0
WINDOW 3 0 64 Center 0
SYMATTR Value XNE567A
SYMATTR Prefix X
SYMATTR SpiceModel XNE567A.sub
SYMATTR Value2 XNE567A
SYMATTR Description An idealized NE567 Tone Decoder with Oscillator
PIN -112 -96 LEFT 8
PINATTR PinName Out Fil C3
PINATTR SpiceOrder 1
PIN -112 -32 LEFT 8
PINATTR PinName Loop Fil C2
PINATTR SpiceOrder 2
PIN -112 32 LEFT 8
PINATTR PinName INPUT
PINATTR SpiceOrder 3
PIN -112 96 LEFT 8
PINATTR PinName Vcc
PINATTR SpiceOrder 4
PIN 112 96 RIGHT 8
PINATTR PinName Time R1
PINATTR SpiceOrder 5
PIN 112 32 RIGHT 8
PINATTR PinName Time R1 C1
PINATTR SpiceOrder 6
PIN 112 -32 RIGHT 8
PINATTR PinName Gnd
PINATTR SpiceOrder 7
PIN 112 -96 RIGHT 8
PINATTR PinName Out OC
PINATTR SpiceOrder 8
```

**Please take note:** There is a line in this file `SYMATTR SpiceModel XNE567A.sub` and this is ***very important***. When LTspice loads up the drawing assembly file and draws it, it also takes note of this line which gives the file name for the model or subcircuit that LTspice should use with this symbol. Make ***sure*** that this name matches up with whatever file name you chose, earlier. Otherwise, LTspice will fail to find the model and will provide an error. This linkage is important for symbols. (Not important if you don't use symbols and prefer to just write out Spice cards.)

The third and fourth files below are two test files you can use to validate the model, itself. These are schematic files. You can place them wherever you want and load them up as a schematic to run.

Michael chose to call this one **XNE567_testA.asc**:

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 880 680
WIRE 48 80 0 80
WIRE 112 80 48 80
WIRE 368 80 336 80
WIRE 480 80 368 80
WIRE 544 80 480 80
WIRE -320 112 -448 112
WIRE -64 144 -64 80
WIRE -32 144 -64 144
WIRE 64 144 32 144
WIRE 112 144 64 144
WIRE 432 144 336 144
WIRE -448 160 -448 112
WIRE -448 160 -496 160
WIRE -64 160 -64 144
WIRE -288 176 -352 176
WIRE 432 176 432 144
WIRE -128 208 -144 208
WIRE 80 208 -64 208
WIRE 112 208 80 208
WIRE 496 208 336 208
WIRE -320 240 -320 112
WIRE -288 240 -320 240
WIRE -496 256 -496 240
WIRE -352 272 -352 176
WIRE 112 272 96 272
WIRE 384 272 336 272
WIRE 416 272 384 272
WIRE 496 272 496 208
WIRE -352 304 -352 272
WIRE 96 320 96 272
WIRE 96 336 96 320
WIRE -496 384 -496 336
WIRE -352 384 -496 384
WIRE -272 384 -352 384
WIRE -272 416 -272 384
FLAG 432 176 0
FLAG 96 416 0
FLAG -64 160 0
FLAG 96 320 5v
FLAG 368 0 5v
FLAG -448 224 0
FLAG -272 416 0
FLAG 480 80 out
FLAG 48 80 Out_Filt
FLAG 64 144 Loop_Filt
FLAG 80 208 Input
FLAG -352 272 Freq
FLAG 384 272 VCO
FLAG 496 336 0
SYMBOL cap 0 64 R90
WINDOW 3 -23 37 VTop 2
WINDOW 0 46 7 VBottom 2
SYMATTR Value .02µ
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMBOL cap 32 128 R90
WINDOW 3 -13 57 VTop 2
WINDOW 0 47 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR Value .01µ
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMBOL cap -64 192 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName C3
SYMATTR Value .01µ
SYMBOL res 352 -16 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL voltage 96 320 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 5
SYMBOL voltage -352 288 R0
WINDOW 123 24 124 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 3 31 72 Left 2
SYMATTR Value 40
SYMATTR InstName V3
SYMBOL SpecialFunctions\\modulate -288 176 R0
WINDOW 3 -22 -50 Left 2
WINDOW 0 51 32 Left 2
SYMATTR Value mark = 1k space = 0
SYMATTR InstName A1
SYMBOL voltage -496 240 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 0 33 54 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -31 -146 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V4
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 150m 0 200u 200u 5m 10m)
SYMBOL res -512 144 R0
WINDOW 0 -19 31 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -36 65 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL cap -464 160 R0
WINDOW 3 32 45 Left 2
SYMATTR Value .04µ
SYMATTR InstName C4
SYMBOL res 512 256 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 2.27k
SYMBOL cap 480 272 R0
SYMATTR InstName C6
SYMATTR Value .01µ
SYMBOL XNE567A 224 176 R0
SYMATTR InstName U1
TEXT -168 296 Left 2 !.tran 0 25m 0 1u
TEXT -312 328 Left 2 ;Frequency
TEXT -528 336 Left 2 ;Pulse Rate/\nAmplitude
```

The following one Michael chose to call **XNE567_testB.asc**. It appears to be a discrete component version of the IC, together with a test harness:

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 1476 1048
WIRE -512 -1504 -848 -1504
WIRE -224 -1504 -512 -1504
WIRE -512 -1440 -512 -1504
WIRE -512 -1360 -576 -1360
WIRE -464 -1360 -512 -1360
WIRE -448 -1360 -464 -1360
WIRE -576 -1344 -576 -1360
WIRE -464 -1344 -464 -1360
WIRE -1184 -1328 -1216 -1328
WIRE -1072 -1328 -1104 -1328
WIRE -1248 -1312 -1328 -1312
WIRE -1328 -1296 -1328 -1312
WIRE -1248 -1296 -1248 -1312
WIRE -1216 -1264 -1216 -1328
WIRE -992 -1264 -1216 -1264
WIRE -704 -1264 -992 -1264
WIRE -576 -1248 -576 -1264
WIRE -576 -1248 -640 -1248
WIRE -464 -1248 -464 -1264
WIRE -368 -1248 -464 -1248
WIRE 0 -1248 -48 -1248
WIRE 32 -1248 0 -1248
WIRE -576 -1216 -576 -1248
WIRE -464 -1216 -464 -1248
WIRE -1328 -1200 -1328 -1216
WIRE -1328 -1200 -1376 -1200
WIRE -1248 -1200 -1328 -1200
WIRE -1216 -1200 -1216 -1264
WIRE -1216 -1200 -1248 -1200
WIRE -1168 -1200 -1216 -1200
WIRE -1072 -1200 -1072 -1328
WIRE -1072 -1200 -1088 -1200
WIRE -784 -1200 -992 -1200
WIRE -848 -1168 -848 -1504
WIRE -704 -1168 -704 -1184
WIRE -640 -1168 -704 -1168
WIRE -352 -1168 -400 -1168
WIRE -1328 -1136 -1376 -1136
WIRE -528 -1120 -576 -1120
WIRE -464 -1120 -528 -1120
WIRE -1328 -1104 -1328 -1136
WIRE -1216 -1104 -1216 -1200
WIRE -1184 -1104 -1216 -1104
WIRE -1104 -1088 -1120 -1088
WIRE -1024 -1088 -1104 -1088
WIRE -912 -1088 -912 -1120
WIRE -912 -1088 -1024 -1088
WIRE -1296 -1072 -1344 -1072
WIRE -1200 -1072 -1216 -1072
WIRE -1184 -1072 -1200 -1072
WIRE -784 -1072 -784 -1200
WIRE -784 -1072 -848 -1072
WIRE -528 -1072 -528 -1120
WIRE -224 -1072 -224 -1504
WIRE 368 -1072 -224 -1072
WIRE 608 -1072 368 -1072
WIRE 928 -1072 608 -1072
WIRE 992 -1072 928 -1072
WIRE 1008 -1072 992 -1072
WIRE -848 -1056 -848 -1072
WIRE -352 -1056 -352 -1088
WIRE 608 -1056 608 -1072
WIRE -416 -1024 -464 -1024
WIRE 928 -1024 928 -1072
WIRE -912 -1008 -912 -1088
WIRE -1200 -992 -1200 -1072
WIRE -1104 -992 -1104 -1088
WIRE -1104 -992 -1120 -992
WIRE -1024 -976 -1024 -1008
WIRE -1024 -976 -1088 -976
WIRE -976 -976 -1024 -976
WIRE -1088 -960 -1088 -976
WIRE -1024 -960 -1024 -976
WIRE 608 -960 608 -976
WIRE 656 -960 608 -960
WIRE 368 -944 368 -992
WIRE 608 -944 608 -960
WIRE -848 -928 -848 -960
WIRE 32 -928 32 -1248
WIRE 96 -928 32 -928
WIRE -1520 -912 -1680 -912
WIRE -1504 -912 -1520 -912
WIRE -1456 -912 -1504 -912
WIRE -1408 -912 -1456 -912
WIRE -1376 -912 -1408 -912
WIRE 448 -896 432 -896
WIRE 544 -896 448 -896
WIRE 928 -896 928 -944
WIRE 1008 -896 1008 -1072
WIRE 1136 -896 1008 -896
WIRE -528 -880 -528 -896
WIRE 1008 -880 1008 -896
WIRE 1136 -864 1136 -896
WIRE 96 -848 96 -864
WIRE 864 -848 608 -848
WIRE -1376 -816 -1376 -832
WIRE 368 -800 368 -848
WIRE 448 -800 448 -896
WIRE 448 -800 368 -800
WIRE 1008 -768 1008 -800
WIRE 1024 -768 1008 -768
WIRE 1056 -768 1024 -768
WIRE 1136 -768 1136 -784
WIRE 1136 -768 1056 -768
WIRE -1744 -752 -1760 -752
WIRE -1680 -752 -1744 -752
WIRE -1520 -752 -1520 -832
WIRE -1520 -752 -1680 -752
WIRE -1264 -752 -1264 -880
WIRE -1264 -752 -1520 -752
WIRE -1056 -752 -1264 -752
WIRE -48 -752 -48 -832
WIRE -48 -752 -416 -752
WIRE 32 -752 32 -928
WIRE 32 -752 -48 -752
WIRE 1008 -736 1008 -768
WIRE -960 -720 -1408 -720
WIRE -928 -720 -960 -720
WIRE -528 -720 -928 -720
WIRE -224 -720 -224 -1072
WIRE -224 -720 -528 -720
WIRE -64 -720 -224 -720
WIRE -1520 -688 -1520 -752
WIRE -1408 -688 -1408 -720
WIRE -1056 -688 -1056 -752
WIRE -960 -688 -960 -720
WIRE -528 -688 -528 -720
WIRE -416 -688 -416 -752
WIRE -64 -688 -64 -720
WIRE 32 -688 32 -752
WIRE 928 -688 928 -800
WIRE 944 -688 928 -688
WIRE -1760 -672 -1760 -688
WIRE 368 -656 368 -800
WIRE 464 -656 368 -656
WIRE 656 -656 656 -960
WIRE 656 -656 576 -656
WIRE -1584 -640 -1600 -640
WIRE -1264 -640 -1344 -640
WIRE -1120 -640 -1264 -640
WIRE -736 -640 -816 -640
WIRE -256 -640 -352 -640
WIRE -128 -640 -256 -640
WIRE -256 -608 -256 -640
WIRE 224 -608 192 -608
WIRE 768 -608 720 -608
WIRE 800 -608 768 -608
WIRE -1408 -592 -1520 -592
WIRE -1008 -592 -1056 -592
WIRE -960 -592 -1008 -592
WIRE -528 -576 -528 -592
WIRE -464 -576 -528 -576
WIRE -416 -576 -416 -592
WIRE -416 -576 -464 -576
WIRE -176 -576 -176 -592
WIRE -64 -576 -64 -592
WIRE 0 -576 -64 -576
WIRE 32 -576 32 -592
WIRE 32 -576 0 -576
WIRE -1264 -560 -1264 -640
WIRE -816 -560 -816 -640
WIRE -816 -560 -1184 -560
WIRE -592 -544 -592 -640
WIRE -176 -544 -176 -576
WIRE -176 -544 -592 -544
WIRE 96 -544 96 -640
WIRE 96 -544 -176 -544
WIRE 944 -544 944 -688
WIRE -1600 -528 -1600 -640
WIRE -896 -528 -896 -640
WIRE -896 -528 -1600 -528
WIRE -1600 -512 -1600 -528
WIRE -1408 -496 -1408 -592
WIRE 192 -496 192 -528
WIRE 464 -496 464 -656
WIRE 576 -496 576 -656
WIRE -1008 -480 -1008 -592
WIRE -1264 -448 -1344 -448
WIRE -1232 -448 -1264 -448
WIRE -736 -448 -848 -448
WIRE 368 -448 368 -560
WIRE 400 -448 368 -448
WIRE 656 -448 656 -560
WIRE 656 -448 640 -448
WIRE -848 -432 -848 -448
WIRE -848 -432 -864 -432
WIRE -464 -432 -464 -576
WIRE -1408 -384 -1408 -400
WIRE -1184 -384 -1408 -384
WIRE -528 -384 -544 -384
WIRE -1408 -368 -1408 -384
WIRE 464 -368 464 -400
WIRE 512 -368 464 -368
WIRE 576 -368 576 -400
WIRE 576 -368 512 -368
WIRE -1152 -352 -1152 -448
WIRE -1120 -352 -1152 -352
WIRE -848 -352 -848 -432
WIRE -848 -352 -1120 -352
WIRE -1264 -336 -1264 -448
WIRE -1216 -336 -1264 -336
WIRE -1008 -336 -1008 -384
WIRE -544 -336 -544 -384
WIRE -544 -336 -1008 -336
WIRE 368 -336 368 -448
WIRE 656 -336 656 -448
WIRE -1008 -320 -1008 -336
WIRE 944 -304 944 -464
WIRE 1008 -304 1008 -640
WIRE 1008 -304 944 -304
WIRE -1408 -272 -1408 -288
WIRE -1264 -272 -1408 -272
WIRE 0 -272 0 -576
WIRE -1408 -256 -1408 -272
WIRE 512 -256 512 -368
WIRE 512 -256 368 -256
WIRE 656 -256 512 -256
WIRE -1264 -240 -1264 -272
WIRE -1008 -240 -1264 -240
WIRE -1184 -192 -1184 -384
WIRE -64 -192 -64 -224
WIRE -64 -192 -1184 -192
WIRE 512 -128 512 -256
WIRE 544 -128 512 -128
WIRE -1408 -112 -1408 -160
WIRE -464 -112 -464 -336
WIRE -224 -112 -464 -112
WIRE 0 -112 0 -176
WIRE 0 -112 -224 -112
WIRE -1216 -80 -1216 -336
WIRE -224 -80 -224 -112
WIRE 688 -80 608 -80
WIRE -1216 -32 -1216 -80
WIRE -288 -32 -352 -32
WIRE -1408 0 -1408 -32
WIRE -1408 0 -1744 0
WIRE -352 0 -352 -32
WIRE -352 0 -416 0
WIRE -1408 16 -1408 0
WIRE 544 16 544 -32
WIRE -224 32 -224 16
WIRE -1216 48 -1216 -32
WIRE 688 48 688 0
WIRE 544 112 544 96
WIRE 944 112 944 -304
WIRE 944 112 544 112
WIRE 544 128 544 112
WIRE -432 144 -560 144
WIRE -352 144 -352 80
WIRE -352 144 -432 144
WIRE -224 144 -224 112
WIRE -224 144 -352 144
WIRE -560 160 -560 144
WIRE -1568 192 -1696 192
WIRE -64 224 -64 176
WIRE -64 224 -432 224
WIRE -1696 240 -1696 192
WIRE -1696 240 -1744 240
WIRE -1536 256 -1600 256
WIRE -1216 288 -1216 112
WIRE -1216 288 -1392 288
WIRE -1568 320 -1568 192
WIRE -1536 320 -1568 320
WIRE -1744 336 -1744 320
WIRE -1600 352 -1600 256
WIRE -1600 384 -1600 352
WIRE -1744 464 -1744 416
WIRE -1600 464 -1744 464
WIRE -1520 464 -1600 464
WIRE -1520 496 -1520 464
FLAG -1408 16 0
FLAG -560 160 0
FLAG -1344 -208 B
FLAG -416 0 B
FLAG -1600 -432 A
FLAG -1376 -816 0
FLAG -1408 -912 5v
FLAG -928 -720 5v
FLAG -48 -912 5v
FLAG -1760 -672 0
FLAG 544 128 0
FLAG 688 48 0
FLAG 768 -608 pin1
FLAG -48 -1248 pin1
FLAG 192 -496 0
FLAG -256 -608 X
FLAG -176 -576 Y
FLAG -1744 -752 Pin2
FLAG -1504 -912 Pin4
FLAG 992 -1072 5v
FLAG 1056 -768 Pin8
FLAG -1216 -32 Pin3
FLAG -1152 -1056 0
FLAG -1152 -1120 5v
FLAG -1344 -992 0
FLAG -1328 -1104 0
FLAG -848 -928 0
FLAG -1216 -1200 Tri
FLAG -1248 -1296 0
FLAG -528 -880 0
FLAG -512 -1440 5v
FLAG -352 -1056 0
FLAG -416 -944 0
FLAG -992 -1264 Tri
FLAG -368 -1248 X
FLAG -640 -1248 Y
FLAG -1024 -880 5v
FLAG -1088 -880 0
FLAG -976 -976 A
FLAG -1264 -880 vl
FLAG -1072 -1200 5
FLAG -1248 -1200 6
FLAG 0 -1248 1
FLAG 1024 -768 8
FLAG -1216 -80 3
FLAG -1680 -752 2
FLAG -1456 -912 4
FLAG -432 224 7
FLAG -64 96 5v
FLAG -1120 -352 M
FLAG -1680 -832 0
FLAG 96 -848 0
FLAG -736 -560 0
FLAG -736 -368 0
FLAG -1696 304 0
FLAG -1520 496 0
FLAG -1600 352 Freq
SYMBOL npn -1584 -688 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q1
SYMBOL npn -1120 -688 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q2
SYMBOL npn -1344 -688 M0
SYMATTR InstName Q3
SYMBOL npn -896 -688 M0
SYMATTR InstName Q4
SYMBOL npn -1344 -496 M0
SYMATTR InstName Q5
SYMBOL npn -944 -480 M0
SYMATTR InstName Q6
SYMBOL npn -1344 -256 M0
SYMATTR InstName Q7
SYMBOL npn -592 -688 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q11
SYMBOL npn -128 -688 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q12
SYMBOL npn -352 -688 M0
SYMATTR InstName Q13
SYMBOL npn 96 -688 M0
SYMATTR InstName Q14
SYMBOL npn -528 -432 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q16
SYMBOL npn -64 -272 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q17
SYMBOL res -1616 -528 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 20k
SYMBOL res -1168 -576 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 -23 19 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL res -800 -656 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL res -848 -448 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R6
SYMATTR Value 21k
SYMBOL res -1136 -464 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R7
SYMATTR Value 21k
SYMBOL res -1424 -384 R0
SYMATTR InstName R8
SYMATTR Value .5k
SYMBOL res -1024 -336 R0
SYMATTR InstName R9
SYMATTR Value .5k
SYMBOL res -1424 -128 R0
SYMATTR InstName R10
SYMATTR Value 2.45k
SYMBOL res -1536 -928 R0
SYMATTR InstName R11
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL npn -288 -80 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q19
SYMBOL res -240 16 R0
SYMATTR InstName R15
SYMATTR Value 2.7k
SYMBOL res -64 -928 R0
SYMATTR InstName R16
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL voltage -352 -16 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V3
SYMATTR Value 1.35
SYMBOL pnp 544 -848 M180
SYMATTR InstName Q20
SYMBOL pnp 432 -848 R180
SYMATTR InstName Q21
SYMBOL npn 304 -656 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q22
SYMBOL npn 400 -496 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q23
SYMBOL npn 640 -496 M0
SYMATTR InstName Q24
SYMBOL npn 720 -656 M0
SYMATTR InstName Q25
SYMBOL res 352 -1088 R0
SYMATTR InstName R18
SYMATTR Value 5k
SYMBOL res 592 -1072 R0
SYMATTR InstName R19
SYMATTR Value 5k
SYMBOL res 352 -352 R0
SYMATTR InstName R20
SYMATTR Value 5k
SYMBOL res 640 -352 R0
SYMATTR InstName R21
SYMATTR Value 5k
SYMBOL npn 608 -128 M0
SYMATTR InstName Q26
SYMBOL res 528 0 R0
SYMATTR InstName R22
SYMATTR Value 5k
SYMBOL voltage 688 -96 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V8
SYMATTR Value 1.4
SYMBOL res 320 -624 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R23
SYMATTR Value 1k
SYMBOL voltage 192 -624 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 0 -39 3 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V9
SYMATTR Value 3.7
SYMBOL npn 864 -896 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q27
SYMBOL npn 944 -736 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q28
SYMBOL res 912 -1040 R0
SYMATTR InstName R24
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL res 928 -560 R0
SYMATTR InstName R26
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL Comparators\\LT1018 -1152 -1088 R0
SYMATTR InstName U1
SYMBOL voltage -1344 -1088 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V6
SYMATTR Value 2.5
SYMBOL res -1200 -1088 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R13
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL res -1104 -1008 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R14
SYMATTR Value 68k
SYMBOL npn -912 -1168 R0
WINDOW 0 30 39 Left 2
WINDOW 3 31 64 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName Q15
SYMATTR Value 2N3904
SYMBOL pnp -912 -960 M180
WINDOW 0 50 30 Left 2
WINDOW 3 42 58 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName Q18
SYMATTR Value 2N3906
SYMBOL npn -640 -1216 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q29
SYMBOL npn -464 -1072 M0
SYMATTR InstName Q30
SYMBOL npn -400 -1216 M0
SYMATTR InstName Q31
SYMBOL res -544 -992 R0
SYMATTR InstName R29
SYMATTR Value 900
SYMBOL res -592 -1360 R0
SYMATTR InstName R30
SYMATTR Value 2k
SYMBOL res -480 -1360 R0
SYMATTR InstName R31
SYMATTR Value 2k
SYMBOL voltage -352 -1184 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V7
SYMATTR Value 2
SYMBOL voltage -416 -1040 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V10
SYMATTR Value 1.22
SYMBOL res -528 -1456 R0
SYMATTR InstName R32
SYMATTR Value 4k
SYMBOL voltage -704 -1168 R180
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 3 14 98 Left 2
SYMATTR Value -.5
SYMATTR InstName V11
SYMBOL res -1040 -1104 R0
SYMATTR InstName R33
SYMATTR Value 6k
SYMBOL res -1040 -976 R0
SYMATTR InstName R34
SYMATTR Value 4.0k
SYMBOL res -1104 -976 R0
SYMATTR InstName R35
SYMATTR Value 12k
SYMBOL bi -1328 -1296 R0
WINDOW 3 -252 -6 Left 2
SYMATTR Value I=(i(R25))*(V(vl)-3.8)*2
SYMATTR InstName B1
SYMBOL res -448 128 R0
SYMATTR InstName R12
SYMATTR Value 10
SYMBOL res -976 -1216 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R25
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL res 992 -896 R0
SYMATTR InstName R27
SYMATTR Value 10Meg
SYMBOL res -80 80 R0
SYMATTR InstName R28
SYMATTR Value 100Meg
SYMBOL res -1072 -1216 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R36
SYMATTR Value 2.27meg
SYMBOL cap -1344 -1200 R0
SYMATTR InstName C4
SYMATTR Value .001f
SYMBOL voltage -736 -656 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 3.8
SYMBOL voltage -736 -464 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value 2.5
SYMBOL res 1120 -880 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL cap 112 -864 R180
WINDOW 0 24 56 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 8 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value .02µ
SYMBOL cap -1776 -752 R0
WINDOW 3 -53 12 Left 2
SYMATTR Value .01µ
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMBOL cap -1392 -1200 R0
WINDOW 0 -15 15 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -34 58 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName C3
SYMATTR Value .01µ
SYMBOL res -1088 -1344 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R5
SYMATTR Value 2.27k
SYMBOL voltage -1680 -928 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V4
SYMATTR Value 5
SYMBOL voltage -1600 368 R0
WINDOW 123 24 124 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 3 31 72 Left 2
SYMATTR Value 40
SYMATTR InstName V5
SYMBOL SpecialFunctions\\modulate -1536 256 R0
WINDOW 3 -22 -50 Left 2
WINDOW 0 51 32 Left 2
SYMATTR Value mark = 1k space = 0
SYMATTR InstName A1
SYMBOL voltage -1744 320 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 0 33 54 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -31 -146 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V12
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 150m 0 200u 200u 5m 10m)
SYMBOL res -1760 224 R0
WINDOW 0 -19 31 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -36 65 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName R17
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL cap -1712 240 R0
WINDOW 3 32 45 Left 2
SYMATTR Value .04µ
SYMATTR InstName C5
SYMBOL cap -1232 48 R0
SYMATTR InstName C6
SYMATTR Value .01µ
TEXT 40 -816 Left 4 ;Output Filter \nCap Pin 1
TEXT -1744 -712 Left 4 ;Loop Filter \nPin 2
TEXT 1184 -840 Left 4 ;External\nPull up
TEXT 1048 -744 Left 4 ;Pin 8
TEXT -1304 -664 Left 4 ;Quad\nPhase
TEXT -320 -488 Left 4 ;In Phase
TEXT -1176 72 Left 4 ;Ext Input \nCap
TEXT -1296 24 Left 4 ;Pin 3
TEXT -1680 -928 Left 4 ;Pin 4
TEXT -1728 -72 Left 4 ;Pin 7\nGround
TEXT -1576 -1208 Left 4 ;Ext Cap\nOscillator
TEXT -1120 -1400 Left 4 ;Ext Resistor\nOscillator
TEXT -1848 -920 Left 4 ;External\nVcc
TEXT -1544 376 Left 2 !.tran 0 25m 0 1u
TEXT -1560 408 Left 2 ;Frequency
TEXT -1776 416 Left 2 ;Pulse Rate/\nAmplitude
TEXT -1680 88 Left 4 ;External Test\nSource
TEXT -928 -88 Left 2 !.lib standard.bjt
```

### summary

Hope that helps out. I've only done a preliminary test using his first test program and it looks good. Also, everything seemed to run as I expected. So no troubles using them.

Comment: Isn't the first one in your list "LTspice IV"?

Comment: @SteKulov Hmm. Yeah, I believe you may be right. I had forgotten that! Thanks. I will make the correction. Appreciated.

Comment: Sure thing.  When I refer to the versions verbally in conversation, I typically say LTspice 4, LTspice 17.0, and LTspice 17.1.  That seems to be the best way to differentiate them with minimal ambiguity (at least in my opinion).

Comment: @SteKulov I'd not tumbled to that. Looking at the About box, I see what you mean. I'm not sure if I'll change my ways. But it's easy to remember if all I do is call up the About box. So maybe I will. Again, thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer. Its exactly what I need. Are the 2 test files required or do I only need them if I want to actually test the models?

Comment: @JasonCrosby You don't need the last two test files for anything if you don't want them. I just grabbed them because they were there to have. (And I liked what they did.) You can ignore them and just move on from the first two. They may be helpful to you, though, should you run into trouble later and not understand what you are doing wrong. They give you a way to evaluate your own methods, if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks again I'm looking forward to getting this added.